# How to find $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{n^2}{7^{\sqrt{n}}}$? I know that it exists and can't find it with Stolz theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How do I find $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{n^2}{7^{\sqrt{n}}}$?

I thought about Stolz theorem so I got:
$$ \frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{7^{\sqrt{n+1}}-7^{\sqrt{n}}}, $$
but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere (at least not through $e$ and $\ln$).

And I know for fact that there is some limit because:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{7^{\sqrt{n+1}}}}{\frac{n^2}{7^{\sqrt{n}}}} = \frac{(n+1)^2*7^{\sqrt{n}}}{7^{\sqrt{n+1}}*n^2} = \frac{(n+1)^2*7^{\sqrt{n}}}{7^{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1}}*n^2} \implies \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}\implies 1$$

Comment: Hint: the limit is $0$. Maybe it is of help to rewrite $1/7^\sqrt{n}$ as $e^{-\sqrt{n}\log 7}$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(2\ln n-\sqrt n\ln 7\right)=0$, because $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}2\ln x-\sqrt x\ln 7=-\infty$.

For the record, you should be warned that Riemann rearrangement theorem implies that for all $0\le x\le y\le\infty$ there is a sequence $a_n>0$ such that $$\begin{cases}\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=x\\ \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=y\\ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1\end{cases}$$

Therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ is inconsequential. Also, while the value of this limit is certainly $1$, I think you made some mistake either of algebra or in manipulation of limits; I won't inspect it any further, because I am not a tutor.

Comment: And why exactly is that: $\lim_{x \to \infty} 2 ln (n) - \sqrt{n} ln (7) = - \infty $????

Comment: @theboyboy Because $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^\alpha}=0$ for all $\alpha>0$, and $-\ln 7<0$.

Comment: Gae. S. The first part can be proven by a squeeze theorem, right?

Comment: @theboyboy I would call the first part just algebra, but arguably everything concerning calculus is a "squeeze theorem".

Comment: @theboyboy Asymptotical considerations about $\ln x$, $e^{ux}$ and $x^\alpha$ are bread and butter of "limit algebra", and they must be in your textbook somewhere, possibly with proof if you're interested (which you may very well be, because they are instructive). You should read them there and then assume them as common knowledge.

Comment: I know that to estimate values in $\infty$ it can be useful that: $1<logn<n<n^2<n^k<2^n<n!$. But to see that I checked functions of $n^{100}$ and $2^n$ and it looks like $n^{100}$ grows faster. And because of that I am not sure if $n^k<2^n$ only for k = 2 or is that true for all k but it can be only seen in $\infty$

Comment: @theboyboy I have already given you my piece of advice. As for the rest, whatever you did which gave you the impression that $n^{100}$ grows faster than $2^n$ as $n\to\infty$, never do that again.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for your comment, it really helped me! Now I know to complement my inequality with $n^k$ with k < 1. It goes like that: $logn<n^k<n$.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere along the timeline you learned that exponential growth wipes out polynomial growth. So if we let $n=x^2,$ we are looking at

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^4}{7^x}.$$

This is polynomial growth divided by exponential growth, and the limit is $0.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: it suffices to consider the subsequence $n_k = k^2$.

Comment: 1st question - why exactly can I do it like that for every $n$? 2nd question - in the squeeze theorem can I just assume that: $n^x < y^n$ for every $x$ and $y$ $\in N$?